# Speech Recognition Using MFCC to rectify pronunciation

Tags: ios, objective-c, signal-processing, speech-recognition, mfcc

I am building a speech recognition application for iOS in objective C/C++ for rectifying the pronunciation of the speaker.
I am using `Mel-Frequency-Cepstrum Coefficients` and Matching the two Sound-Waves using `DTW.`
Please correct me if I am wrong. 
Now I want to know that which word in the sentence (two sound files) mismatches.
e.g. My two sound files speak

```
 1. I live in New York.
 2. I laav in New York.
```

My algorithm should some how point to 2nd word by some sort of indication.

I have used Match-Box open library for reference. Here is its [link](https://github.com/hfink/matchbox).
Any new algorithm or any new library is welcome.

```
PS. I don't want to use text to speech synthesis and speaker recognition.
```

Please direct me to right resources if I have posted question at wrong place.

Any little hint is also welcomed.